rsync from Ubuntu Linux to Windows 11 with OpenSSH server
This article indicates the OpenSSH server optional feature in Windows 11 can be used to support rsync from Linux.
After installing OpenSSH server as suggested in the article above, (from Settings/Apps/Optional Apps, not in the WSL) and starting the service with Start-Service sshd I am able to connect using SSH from the Ubuntu machine successfully
From the Linux terminal (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), it provides a Windows terminal with a prompt like me@windowshost C:\Users\Me>
From the Ubuntu terminal I tried a command like this (as suggested in article):
rsync -avP --rsync-path='wsl rsync' /home/me me@windowshost:\\Users\\Me\\folder

After prompting for password, rsync displays:
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(600) [sender=3.2.3]

The rsync man page suggests running $ ssh hostname > /bin/true > out.dat to learn if a shell is not "clean". I ran that and got The system cannot find the path specified. at the terminal. The file out.dat was created with 0 bytes. I'm not sure how to interpret that.
I noticed in the rsync command includes "wsl". But the title of the linked article is "How to rsync directly into a Windows 10 machine (using OpenSSH not cygwin or WSL)"
Is the command actually expecting WSL on the Windows system? Is it still necessary to use WSL on Windows to support rsync?

There's no rsync in Win32-OpenSSH.
While the article you refer to gives an impression that it does not depend on WSL, the --rsync-path='wsl rsync' in the rsync command-line indeed proves the opposite. It depends on rsync in the WSL.
